# UIView or UIViewController as the starting point for a reusable custom view

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, reusability, custom-view

I'm developing a fairly complicated UI component that will be delivered as a reusable component. Normally, it will cover the entire screen of the hosting application, but there's a use case where it will be presented along side other UI elements of the hosting application. Given its complexity, I lean towards subclassing UIViewController. However, that seems to be complicating things for the hosting application (?). So, what are the pros on cons for starting from a UIView vs. starting from a UIViewController?